# Find all Super Powers

Tags: code-golf, math

A positive number is said to be super power when it is the power of at least two different positive integers. Write a program that lists all super powers in the interval [1, 2<sup>64</sup>) (i.e. between 1 (inclusive) and 2<sup>64</sup> (exclusive)).

Sample Output

```
1
16
64
81
256
512
.
.
.
18443366605910179921
18444492376972984336
18445618199572250625
```

Constraints:

1. The program should not take more than 10 secs.
2. There are 67385 super powers below 2<sup>64</sup>.
3. The shortest code wins.

Comment: The time part is a quite severe limitation on environment, many slow consoles will be out because they basically can't do 10k lines per second.

Comment: @eBusiness Keeping in mind your point, should 20 secs be enough?

Comment: I think it might just do it for my GolfScript, but I'd rather make it a minute.

Comment: @eBusiness: What if you output to file instead?

Comment: That helps, put me down to less than 3 seconds for the output. Now to see if I can do the actual task quick enough...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## GolfScript 52 characters

```
64,4>{1.{16.?<}{;).2$?}/@.,1>{2$\%*}**!*\;~}%$.&{p}/
```

I golfed this pretty heavily, here is a compilation of midway solutions:

```
;64,4>{.,2>{\.@%}%{*}*!\;},{1.{16.?<}{;).2$?}/]2=}%[]*$0\{.@={}{.p}if}/;
;64,4>{.,2>{\.@%}%{*}*!\;},{1.{16.?<}{;).2$?}/]2=}%[]*$.&{p}/
;64,4>{.,2>{\.@%}%{*}*!\;},{1.{16.?<}{;).2$?}/]2=~}%$.&{p}/
;4.{64<}{;)..,1>{2$\%*}*!*}/0-\;{1.{16.?<}{;).2$?}/]2=~}%$.&{p}/
;64,4>{.,1>{2$\%*}*!*},{1.{16.?<}{;).2$?}/]2=~}%$.&{p}/
;64,4>{.,1>{2$\%*}*{1.{16.?<}{;).2$?}/~}or]2>~}%$.&{p}/
64,4>{.,1>{2$\%*}*!\1.{16.?<}{;).2$?}/\;\;*~}%$.&{p}/
64,4>{1.{16.?<}{;).2$?}/\;\.,1>{2$\%*}*!\;*~}%$.&{p}/
64,4>{1.{16.?<}{;).2$?}/@.,1>{2$\%*}**!*\;~}%$.&{p}/
```

GolfScript seems to have some problem with outputting large arrays, therefore I step through the result array using `{p}/` rather than just inject the needed lineshifts using `n*`.

The first 5 versions work by first generating an array of nonprimes from 4 to 63 (code before `{1.`), then for each element of that list all N^nonprime less than 2^64 is calculated (`1.{16.?<}{;).2$?}/`). Finally the result is sorted, duplicates are removed and the result is output.

In the 6th version the 2 first functions are put in the same loop.

In the 7th version the N^nonprime array is generated no matter if the nonprime is actually a nonprime, the array is then thrown away if needed.

In the 8th and 9th version the order has been switched so the N^nonprime array is generated before nonprime status is asserted.

By the way, a^b where a>0, b>1 and b is nonprime is probably a more programming-friendly way of describing super powers.

Answer (score 5):

### Ruby, <del>97</del> 93 characters

```
puts (r=2..32).map{|j|r.map{|i|(1..2**(64.0/j/i)).map{|a|a**(j*i)}}}.flatten.uniq.sort[0..-2]
```

I'm pretty sure this should be correct.

```
$ time ruby1.9 perfectpower.rb > out

real    0m0.199s
user    0m0.160s
sys     0m0.030s

$ wc -l out
67385 out

$ head -6 out
1
16
64
81
256
512

$ tail -3 out
18443366605910179921
18444492376972984336
18445618199572250625
```

Answer (score 3):

### Python, 107 chars

```
R=range
for x in sorted(set(i**(j*k)for i in R(65536)for j in R(2,32)for k in R(2,64/j)))[1:67386]:print x
```

Takes about 40 seconds on my machine, though.

Comment: Well, you do make a set of several million numbers, up to 1024 bit in length. May I suggest that you move `for i in R` to the other end of the for stack and give it a sensible limit like `ceil(2^(64/j/k)+2)`?